# Constrict special attack in wildshape form

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, constrict

Is there any way for a wild shaped druid that turns into an animal without constrict (ie. Giant Lake Octopus) to be able to apply constrict to that form via a magical item or other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Belt, Anaconda’s Coils](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-anaconda-s-coils/)**

> In addition, the belt grants the wearer the constrict ability for 1d6 points of damage plus the wearer’s Strength modifier.

Pretty straightforward, and does work while [Polymorphed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph).

> Items that provide constant bonuses and do not need to be activated continue to function while melded

**[Backbreaker Mail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/backbreaker-mail/)**

> This armor grants its wearer the constrict ability, dealing an amount of damage equal to 1d6 + the wearer’s Strength modifier.

This one being armor, you'd have to also have the [Wild](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/wild/) special ability, making the suit very costly. It's also got some anti-human vibes, so you might have to reconcile that, depending on your character.

Comment: Doesn't the belt of anaconda coils only work in human form?

Comment: @Atalius From [Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph): `Items that provide constant bonuses and do not need to be activated continue to function while melded`. The constrict ability the belt provides does not need to be activated in any way, you always have it.

Comment: I updated the answer to include that.

Comment: It's a debatable sentence, really: Grammatically, it should be read as, "Items (that [*both*] provide constant bonuses *and* do not need to be activated] continue to function while melded" (emphasis mine), because there's only one *that* and strongly implying other melded items *don't* continue to function. Most folks read it more generously, though.

Comment: great! now would that apply to each of the 9 attacks? meaning constrict/release 9 times (if GM allows this) and on a secondary attack such as a tentacle would the constrict STR bonus damage be half or full?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I suppose it can be read like that, and I have no idea whether that was the author's intent. As always the final interpretation is up to the GM.

Comment: @Atalius constrict is per grapple check. If your GM allows you to grab and release for each attack, then the constrict will be applied each time. The damage will always be +Str, and doesn't depend on the attack used. [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96083/how-do-free-grapples-grapple-feats-interact-with-full-attacks-and-additional-gra)

Comment: Do the rules state that I can only grab and constrict one time (assuming I do not release)? Can I simultaneously grab and constrict the same target with two or three tentacles? And one last question would I be able to grab and constrict with my first tentacle (keeping the grapple going) and continue with my other 8 normal tentacle attacks without constricting?

Comment: @Atalius Those are *really good* questions and should probably stand alone.